# Cython unable to properly access data from file containing shared data in python

Tags: python, numpy, class, cython

I have two Cython functions that access data from a shared class in python both functions use the same method to gather the data from the class but only one works.

Function 1 (gathers data without any problems)

```py
cpdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] forward_propagate(np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] inputs, list activation_list):
    weights = WeightVals.Weights
    neurons = NeuronVals.Neurons
    neurons[0]= inputs
    # activation_list -> a list of lambda functions
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim = 1] layer_outputs
    for layer, weight in enumerate(weights):
        layer_outputs = np.dot(neurons[layer], weight)
        neurons[layer+1] = activation_list[layer](layer_outputs)
    return neurons[-1]
```

Function 2 (WeightVals.Weights returns a [] even though no modifications to the list have been made)

```py
cpdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] back_propagate(np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] loss,  list activation_derv_list ):
    derv = DerivativeVals.Derivatives
    neurons = NeuronVals.Neurons
    weights = WeightVals.Weights

    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim = 1] delta
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim = 2] delta_reshape, current_reshaped
    for layer in reversed(range(len(derv))):
        delta = loss * activation_derv_list[layer](neurons[layer+1])
        delta_reshape = delta.reshape(delta.shape[0], -1).T
        current_reshaped = neurons[layer].reshape(neurons[layer].shape[0], -1)
        derv[layer] = np.dot(current_reshaped, delta_reshape)
        loss = np.dot(delta, WeightVals.Weights[layer].T)
        print("check")
```

I've tried allocating weights just to the "back_propagate" function and edited the imports

```py
from deeprai.engine.base_layer import DerivativeVals, WeightVals, NeuronVals
```

I expected WeightVals to have the value of whatever the weights are but it returns an empty list.

Comment: This kind of question needs an [mre]. This is fairly close but requires us to fill in a reasonable amount of code to try to reproduce it

Comment: (asside: none of this code looks like it would benefit from your Cython typing at all.)